# what is the output of return sequence lstm keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a tensor with shape `Q = (?,15,512)`

```
Out  = LSTM( 512  ,input_shape=(15,512) ,return_sequences='true') (Q)
```

the Out shape is **(?,?,512)**

I know the first ? is batch size but what is the second ?

Answer (score 1):

return_sequences=True

The above line returns the full sequence and that is the second parameter.
[Link to the docs](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm)

Comment: make the answer better by adding a link to the source.

Comment: @putonspectacles Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Lstm exepect input in the form of [samples, time steps, features]. When return sequence is set true, the values returned will be equal to the number of time steps, that is 15 in your case.

Refer here for the complete api definition:
https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm